# Active class being added to the HTML but not its properties

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, angular-directive

I've got a navigation menu which I want to add an `active` class to once it's clicked. It works great apart from the fact that the element doesn't receive the properties in the `active` class, it just gets added to the HTML as a class. I've also tried using `$compile` in my directive to ensure that the `active` class gets added but it still doesn't work. What am I missing here?

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="app-navigation" class="clearfix list">
    <li data-my-active-class>
        <img src="images/add.png" no-repeat class="nav-image">
    </li>
    <li data-my-active-class>
        <img src="images/edit.png" no-repeat class="nav-image">
    </li>
    <li data-my-active-class>
        <img src="images/delete.png" no-repeat class="nav-image">
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Directive:**

```
shoppingApp.directive('myActiveClass', ['$compile', function($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

            element.on('click', function() {

                element.parent().children('.active').removeClass('.active');
                element.addClass('.active');
            });

            $compile(element)($scope);
        }
    }
}]);
```

**CSS:**

```
.active {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: [This question is off-topic (#2)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `addClass` and `removeClass` make it `active` instead of `.active`

Comment: And that's why you don't code during the night.. Didn't even notice I had punctuation marks. Cheers.

Comment: Haha have fun coding.